# Packets incapsulation for own simple VPN

Tags: c, networking, protocols, vpn, ipsec

I want to do my own very simple implementation of VPN in C on Linux. For that purpose I'm going to capture IP packets, modify them and send forward. The modification consists of encryption, authentication and other stuff like in IPSec. My question is should I process somehow the size of packets or this will be handled automatically? I know it's maximum size is 65535 - 20 (for header) but accoring to MTU it is lesser. I think its because encrypted payload "incapsulated into UDP" for NAT-T is much bigger then just "normal payload" of the IP packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that there actually 2 ways to handle that problem:

1) We can send big packets by settings DF flag to tell we want fragment out packets. But in this case packet can be lost, because not all the devices/etc support packet fragmentation

2) We can automatically calculate our maximum MTU between hosts, split them and send. On another side we put all this packets together and restore them. This can be done by implementing our own "system" for this purpose.

More about IP packets fragmentation and reassembly you can read [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/25885-pmtud-ipfrag.html)